# How can I get legends to display correctly for a grouped bar chart using the BriteChart.js library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Example Of what I want (the labels at the bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp7C6.png);

I have tried adding the leggends as follows:

```
// Add legends to the chart
 var legend = new britecharts.legend();
 legend.width(300);
 legend.height(300);
 legend.colorSchema(barChart1.colorSchema());
 legend.margin({top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 10});

d3.select(".tickets-logged-legend").datum(barData).call(legend);
```

But this is the result:
[Legends do not display like it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKwPj.png)

The legends should actually display a Venue Name like "Venue 1". It looks a bit wierd, because I only have one venue in the data currently. The legends displays the products and not the venues and the color mappings are wrong.